# How to display translated options for list(text) fields with field_view_field()?

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I have set up a list(text) field with translated content.

In display admin interface (admin/structure/types/manage/***/display), I have set up it to "Default translated" in "format" column. Then if I display the node, the options are well translated.

But when I try to load this field programmatically, I have always the main language displayed (instead the translation).

Here is the way I proceed.

```
$specialisations = field_view_field('node', $node_object, 'field_sp_cialisations_liste', array('type' => 'i18n_list_default','label' => 'hidden'));

render($specialisations)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass $langcode parameter in [field_view_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7) function

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately this is not working too: $specialisations = field_view_field('node', $node_object, 'field_sp_cialisations_liste', array('type' => 'i18n_list_default','label' => 'hidden'), $langcode = 'fr');